# Why are str(repr(p)) and print(repr(p)) not the same?

Tags: python, string, repr

I've read in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr) all the answers, but I got stuck in the following example:

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65164408/14438683):

```
class Person:
     pass

p=Person()
```

According to this source, if you call `repr(p)` you will get this as default:

```
<__main__.Person object at 0x7fb2604f03a0>
```

However, I called `repr(p)` on the python shell and I got this:

```
>>> repr(p)
'<__main__.Person object at 0x000001F1C0B1A2E0>'
```

As far as my understanding goes, there's a huge difference between the both: the latter is python expression, in this way, it can be used in `eval()`.

Because I got two different results, I tried to pin down the cause, which I think I did.

```
>>>print(repr(p))
<__main__.Person object at 0x0000021D032392E0>
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), `object.__str__(self)` is called when you use `str(object)` and `print(object)`, so I tried this:

```
x = print(repr(p))
y = str(repr(p))
>>> x == y
False
```

Comparison:

```
>>> print(repr(p))
<__main__.Person object at 0x0000021D032392E0>
>>> str(repr(p))
'<__main__.Person object at 0x0000021D032392E0>'
```

---

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63464185/14438683),

> In the Python shell (interactive interpreter), if you enter a variable at the >>> prompt and press RETURN, the interpreter displays the results of repr() implicitly called on that object.

`repr()` is being called behind the scenes, meaning that, on the python shell, `>>> p` returns `repr(p)`.

```
<__main__.Person object at 0x000002184030A2E0>
```

`>>> repr(p)` returns `repr(repr(p))`, that is, `repr(<__main__.Person object at 0x000002184030A2E0>)`.

```
'<__main__.Person object at 0x000002184030A2E0>'
```

However, I'm not sure why `print(repr(p))` and `str(repr(p))` differ on the python shell, don't they both call the same function?

Comment: `print()` doesn't put quotes around a string. The REPL does.

Comment: `x = print(whatever)` sets `x` to `None`, because `print` returns `None` after printing `whatever` to the console.

Comment: `x = print(repr(p))` is `None`

Comment: The argument is irrelevant; the problem is that `str` and `print` do two entirely different things.

Comment: In summary, `print()` calls `object.__str__(self)` just like `str(object)`, but returns `None`, right?

Comment: Yes, but it also writes to standard output, which `str` does not. The two are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point of confusion here is around how `print` and the REPL work.  You can eliminate `repr` from the situation entirely and just use string literals to observe when you see the quotes and when you don't:

```
>>> "foo"
'foo'
>>> print("foo")
foo
>>> x = print("foo")
foo
>>> x
>>> x is None
True
```

When you see `'foo'`, it's the REPL showing you the (`eval`-able) value of the string expression you just typed in.  When you see `foo` without the quotes, it's a side effect of having called `print`, which prints the actual contents of the string.  `print` also returns `None`, as demonstrated by evaluating `x is None` after assigning its result to `x`.  Note that the REPL does not echo `None` to the console when it evaluates an expression that returns `None`.

Comment: "Note that the REPL does not echo None to the console when it evaluates an expression that returns `None`." It returns nothing instead, right?

Comment: It echoes nothing at all, correct.  Note that when I just input `x` (which is `None`) there's nothing, not even an empty line.

Comment: Why doesn't `repr(None)` return anything? I can't find information about it on the documentation.

Comment: `repr(None)` returns the string `'None'`.  You might still be confused by the difference between *returning* a value and *printing* a value (due to the fact that the REPL automatically prints any non-None return value).

Comment: It's clear now thank you. I didn't know that REPL did that, the books I've read never mentioned such thing.